# How to assign a group to user as the time of signup in class based view in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am using class based views in my djanog project. i need to assign a group named 'customer' (from django.contrib.auth.Group) at the time of when a user signsup (register)

this is my view for signup

```
class UserSignup(SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = 'users/signup.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
    form_class = UserSignupForm
    success_message = 'Account Created with the name of %{first_name} %{last_name}'
```

Answer (score 1):

figured out by own

we will need to inherit post method and can assign group to user

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        result = super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
        group = Group.objects.get(name='Customer') 
        group.user_set.add(self.object)
        return result
```